# Gráfico comparativo de modelos exponenciales

Tags: r

Tengo un diseño experimental factorial 3x3 y deseo realizar una regresión no lineal para ajustar exponencialmente. Puedo sin mayor problema ajustar las curvas individualmente de la siguiente forma:

```
dataUrea0 <- subset(Suelo, Nurea == "0")
dataUrea90 <- subset(Suelo, Nurea == "90")
dataUrea180 <- subset(Suelo, Nurea == "180")

plotPoints(P ~ NCP, data = dataUrea0)
nlsUrea0 <- nls(P~a*exp(b*NCP), dataUrea0, start=list(a= 5, b=0.04))
summary(nlsUrea0)
pcrGOF(nlsUrea0, PRESS = FALSE)
overview(nlsUrea0)
plotfit(nlsUrea0, smooth = TRUE, xlab="Norg (Kg/ha)", ylab="P (ppm)", col.fit = "blue", lwd = 3)

plotPoints(P ~ NCP, data = dataUrea90)
nlsUrea90 <- nls(P~a*exp(b*NCP), dataUrea90, start=list(a= 5, b=0.04))
summary(nlsUrea90)
pcrGOF(nlsUrea90, PRESS = FALSE)
overview(nlsUrea90)
plotfit(nlsUrea90, smooth = TRUE, xlab="Norg (Kg/ha)", ylab="P (ppm)", col.fit = "blue", lwd = 3)

plotPoints(P ~ NCP, data = dataUrea180)
nlsUrea180 <- nls(P~a*exp(b*NCP), dataUrea180, start=list(a= 5, b=0.04))
summary(nlsUrea180)
pcrGOF(nlsUrea180, PRESS = FALSE)
overview(nlsUrea180)
plotfit(nlsUrea180, smooth = TRUE, xlab="Norg (Kg/ha)", ylab="P (ppm)", col.fit = "blue", lwd = 3)
```

Sin embargo cuando deseo hacer un gráfico comparativo obtengo un error. Yo escribo en el r:

```
S <- within(S, {
  Nmin <- as.factor(NM)
})
S <- within(S, {
  Norg <- as.factor(NCP)
})
S$Tratamiento <- as.factor(S$Tratamiento)

S%>%
  split(.$NM) %>%
  map( ~nls(P~a*exp(b*Norg)),
              start = list(a = 5),
                           (b = 0.04),
              trace = TRUE, 
              algorithm = "port", 
              data=.) %>% 
  map_df(~augment(.), .id="NM") %>% 
  as.tibble() %>%                      
  ggplot(aes(x=Norg, y=P, color=NM)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=.fitted))+
  labs(title="",
       x="x",  
       y="y")+
  theme_minimal()
```

Y obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Error: `.x` is not a vector (language)
```

Para realizar todo esto uso las librerías:

```
library(mosaic)
library(ggplot2)
library(nlstools)
library(minpack.lm)
library(qpcR)
library(broom)
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)
```

Aquí les dejo una muestra de los datos:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fvg26kaihxgg9rd/S.xlsx?dl=0
Gracias!

Comment: Hola Germán. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo del código con el que generás sin problemas las curvas individualmente? Entiendo que con ese código es con el que ajustas el modelo `stats::nls()`. Para tratar de identificar el problema intenté generar el modelo sin usar el `map` a partir de tu código y me da un error de especificación en el modelo en el que la línea más informativa dice:  `Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model`. Eso sería un error en los datos o en la especificación del modelo, más que el iterador de listas.

Comment: Germán, son dos preguntas relacionadas, pero diferentes. Te sugiero formularlas por separado.

Comment: Hola @mpaladino, edite la pregunta según los comentarios que me dejaste, dando los ejemplos y formulando otra pregunta aparte.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Gracias! Si te fijas en el código que funciona vas a encontrar el problema en `start = list ()`. Ya puse una respuesta más abajo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Germán,

tu código tiene dos problemas, uno de sintaxis y otro de tipos de datos.

El problema de sintaxis es que hay varios paréntesis mal situados en la línea del `map`, por eso la función no encuentra los datos y regresa el error `.x is not a vector`. En estos casos te sugiero probar el código que vas a vectorizar con `map()` por separado, eso facilita obtener errores informativos. Al estar usando `map()` los errores que regresa no son muy útiles para encontrar el problema. Además como la sintaxis es más simples es más fácil contar los paréntesis y verificar la ubicación de las comas, que es lo que está fallando en tu código.

Solucionado el error de sintaxis aparece un segundo error, de tipo de datos: `Norg` no debe ser factor, sino numérico. Si miras tu código verás que los usas para una operación aritmética en `b*Norg`. Posiblemente `nls()` coercione ese factor a numérico, dando números enteros mayores que 1. Es posible que el modelo falle por eso.

## Solución

```
S%>%                                  # S son los datos leídos del xlsx en DropBox
  mutate(Norg=NCP) %>%                #Reemplaza a S <- within(S, {Norg <- as.factor(NCP)}) y además no lo hace factor.
  split(.$NM) %>%
  map( ~nls(P~a*exp(b*Norg),
       start = list(a = 5, b = 0.04),  # Acá había un error, (b = 0.04) quedaba fuera de la lista start
       trace = TRUE, 
       algorithm = "port", 
       data=.)) %>%                   #Acá faltaba un paréntesis.
  map_df(~augment(.), .id="NM") %>%   #De acá salen los warnigns
  as.tibble() %>%       
  mutate(NM=factor(NM, c("0", "90", "180"))) %>% #Paso NM a factor y le doy un orden específico, que se reflejará en las etiquetas de leyenda. 
  ggplot(aes(x=Norg, y=P, color=NM)) +
    geom_line(aes(y=.fitted))+
    labs(title = "",
             x = "x",  
             y = "y") +
    theme_minimal()
```

A mí me regresa el gráfico que estás buscando, con una línea para nivel de `NM`, ordenada de 0 a 180.
Este código funciona, aunque produce unos `warning` que no son preocupantes. Creo que por el uso que hace `augment()` de una función obsoleta. Nada grave, por ahora.

Comment: La solución funciono, pero ¿cómo puedo hacer para que el gráfico que genere el código quede con las curvas de los modelos y no por puntos unidos por las lineas? ¿Y para que la leyenda me quede en orden creciente? Gracias

Comment: Para la leyenda podrías hacerlo reordenando el factor con el controla color=, en este caso NM. De ahí sale el orden y puedes hacerlo antes de graficar o directamente en la llamada de ggplot. Busca en SO "reordenar factores", algo debe haber. Para el otro problema te señalé un solución en SO en en inglés en una respuesta anterior. Saludos

Comment: Vi la solución en ingles que me compartiste anteriormente y el problema que tuve fue que al tener pocos puntos la función geom_smooth realiza lineas erráticas que no son el gráfico que calcule. El problema lo resolví creando una nueva base de datos con mas puntos y con la función predict y geom_smooth logre obtener el gráfico. Lo que no pude hacer es ordenar los factores y no encontré nada en SO que me explicara como hacerlo, intente usar la función geom_density sin mucho resultado.
Muchas gracias!
Saludos

Comment: Germán, es verdad, el tema no estaba tratado en SO. Agregué una línea para reordenar el factor NM, con eso se ordenan las etiquetas de leyenda. De todos estaría bueno que formules una pregunta sobre el tema (algo así como "¿Como reordenar las etiquetas de un ggplot"?) para que si alguien lo busca más adelante lo encuentre con facilidad. Además podrías tener más y mejores respuestas con métodos para hacerlo. Saludos