# ¿Cómo reordenar las etiquetas de un ggplot?

Tags: r

Tengo varios factores que deseo gráficar en un mismo cuadro para compararlos.
Yo separo la base de datos según los factores (en este caso "0", "90" y "180", hago una regresión no lineal de cada uno de ellos, hago una predicción de datos (con los datos originales no se porque no se me dibujaba bien la recta) y cuando deseo hacer un gráfico comparativo los factores de la leyenda quedan desordenados.

Yo realizo:

```
  newdataS%>%
  mutate(Norg=NCP) %>%
  split(.$NU) %>%
  map( ~nlsLM(P_predicted_vals~a*exp(b*Norg),
            start = list(a = 5, b = 0.04),
            trace = TRUE, 
            algorithm = "port", 
            data=.)) %>% 
  map_df(~augment(.), .id="NU") %>%
  as.tibble() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Norg, y=P_predicted_vals, color=NU)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=.fitted)) +
  labs(title = "",
       x = "Norg",  
       y = "P",
       color = "Kg") +
  theme_minimal()
```

¿Cómo puedo ordenar los factores en la leyenda?
Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Se ordena los factores de la siguiente forma:

```
newdataS%>%
  mutate(Norg=NCP) %>%
  split(.$NU) %>%
  map( ~nlsLM(P_predicted_vals~a*exp(b*Norg),
            start = list(a = 5, b = 0.04),
            trace = TRUE, 
            algorithm = "port", 
            data=.)) %>% 
  map_df(~augment(.), .id="NU") %>%
  as.tibble() %>% 
mutate(NM=factor(NM, c("0", "90", "180"))) %>% #Paso NM a factor y le doy un orden específico, que se reflejará en las etiquetas de leyenda.
  ggplot(aes(x=Norg, y=P_predicted_vals, color=NU)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=.fitted)) +
  labs(title = "",
       x = "Norg",  
       y = "P",
       color = "Kg") +
  theme_minimal()
```

La respuesta original se fue realizada por @mpaladino en:
[Gráfico comparativo de modelos exponenciales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135357/gr%C3%A1fico-comparativo-de-modelos-exponenciales/135496?noredirect=1#comment254570_135496)

Se realizo la pregunta de nuevo para cuando alguien tenga el mismo problema le sea más fácil encontrarla.