# Ver la ecuación de regresión en un gráfico

Tags: r, ggplot2

He conseguido hacer un gráfico empleando un script que me pasaron y tengo la duda que aparece líneas abajo del script.

```
plot <- df %>%
  group_by(Alimento=round(Alimento0)) %>%   
    summarise(muL=mean(PesoNacer),
              muF=mean(PesoSacrificio),
              muP=mean(PesoNeto)) %>%
  melt(., id.vars="peso")%>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x=peso, y=value)) +  
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free") + 
  geom_point(color="gray70")+ 
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ poly(x,3), method = "lm") + #Exactamente qué está haciendo? Aplicando un polinomio cúbico a los datos y ajustándolos mediante una regresión lineal?
  theme_light()

print(plot1)
```

A parte de la duda, quisiera saber cómo puedo ver la ecuación de regresión y los parámetros del ajuste del modelo, ya sea el R o R2.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Respuesta corta:

Sí, hace exactamente lo que dices en el comentario al código.

## Respuesta larga

En `ggplot2::geom_smooth()` grafica la pendiente de un modelo. Para conocer los puntos debe ajustar el modelo. Por defecto (si no agregas nada a la llamada de `geom_smooth` ajusta un modelo general aditivo -GAM), pero eso se puede cambiar.

En el ejemplo que das:

- `method`: indica el método o función que usará para ajustar el modelo. En tu caso `method = "lm"` ajustará un modelo lineal con la función `lm()`
- `formula`: en la que se especifica el modelo. Recta, cuadrática, polinómica, etc.

## Ver las cantidades de interés de un modelo que se graficado con `geom_smooth`

Si tenemos el código para hacer el gráfico ahí también tenemos toda la información para ajustar el modelo y ver pendientes, errores, estadísticos de diagnóstico, etc.

Lo hacemos ajustando un modelo con el método y la fórmula especificados.

```
modelo_polinomial_cúbico <- lm(y ~ poly(x,3), data = mis_datos)
```

y explorarlo con

```
summary(modelo_polinomial_cúbico)
```

En el ejemplo que das deberías tomar los datos que produce la tubería hasta justo antes de la llamada a `ggplot`.

> Por lo que veo al estar usando `facet_wrap` en tu ejemplo se ajusta el modelo para más de una serie de datos. Se podría reproducir ese comportamiento en el ajuste de modelos por fuera de `ggplot` usando `split()` y pasando el modelo con `lapply` o similar. Sin un ejemplo de los datos es difícil ver la forma puntual de hacerlo. Quizás [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135357/gr%C3%A1fico-comparativo-de-modelos-exponenciales/135496#135496) te sirva de guía, trata un tema parecido.